# <form:options tag spring mvc binding

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, binding, controller

I am binding a list with Spring MVC form select box like this given below

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${instance.parameters}" varStatus="itemsRow">
    <form:select size="6" path="parameters[${itemsRow.index}].parmvalues" multiple="true">

        <form:options items="${item.pluginParmvalues}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="parmValue" />

    </form:select>
</c:forEach>
```

After binding this `<form:select` displays values correctly. But when I try to save it it throws exception. Should I also bind `<form:options` values to something like this

```
<form:options path="parameters[${itemsRow.index}].parmvalues[0].parmValue"
```

instead of `items="${item.pluginParmvalues}"` to get/save values in controller?

### Exception:

Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.domain.Parmvalue] for property 'parmvalues[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]

Comment: putting a 'path' attribute on the options tag does not make any sense, no.  What is the exception?  You appear to be attempting to bind a single integer onto an entire list...?  (parmvalues is a list, but yuo're binding a single parmValue onto it...?)

Comment: yes you are right. exception added

Comment: You need to register some type of property editor to tell spring how to convert the id you bound back into a Parmvalue object.  There are several ways to do this depending on version of spring and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way select box is not being bounded. You have to take a hidden field and bind that hidden field with `path="parameters[${itemsRow.index}].parmvalues"`. Each time select box value is changed. Change value of that hidden field too through javascript/jquery.